# Wouldnt the electric potential energy be constantly decreasing in a circuit and not just at points of resistance?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, voltage

Good day,

I am a beginner in electrical engineering.I was wondering when the positive charge is passing through the circuit isn’t it constantly losing electrical potential energy as it is flowing from positive to negative point?  Then shouldn’t we get a voltage when we put a voltmeter at point A and B in a circuit since the potential electrical energy at point B would be lesser than at point A ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, as long as there is electrical impedance, such as resistance, between points A and B.  I say this because points A and B in your diagram appear to be on a connecting wire in the circuit. In circuit analysis the resistance of wires connecting circuit components is usually ignored (considered zero) since it is generally considered to be much less than the components in the circuit. Technically,  however, it is never zero except for super conductors.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no resistance then there is no voltage drop. This is what Ohm'slaw tells you. In this sense you are asking if Ohm's law is wrong. Ohm's law however is correct.